# Kubernetes Ingress (Specific APP) 504 Gateway Time-Out with 60 seconds

Tags: kubernetes, timeout

We have an environment with k8s + Rancher 2 (3 nodes) and an external nginx that only forwards connections to the k8s cluster according to this documentation: [https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026102822/https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/)

In a specific application running in this environment, when we perform a POST (since this POST takes around 3 to 4 minutes to complete), it is interrupted with the message "504 Gateway Time-Out" after 60 seconds. I've tried to apply specific notes to change the timeout as below, but to no avail:

Ingress of application:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-loteamento-spring-hml
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: "keepalive_timeout 3600s;client_body_timeout 3600s;client_header_timeout 3600s;"
  labels:
    run: api-loteamento-spring-hml
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hml-api-loteamento-sp.gruposfa.bla.bla
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-loteamento-spring-hml
          servicePort: 80
```

I have also tried to create a Global ConfigMap with the parameters as below, also without success:

```
[rancher@srv-rcnode01 ssl]$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-67cf578fc4-lcz82   1/1     Running   1          38d
nginx-ingress-controller-7jcng          1/1     Running   11         225d
nginx-ingress-controller-8zxbf          1/1     Running   8          225d
nginx-ingress-controller-l527g          1/1     Running   8          225d
```

```
[rancher@srv-rcnode01 ssl]$ kubectl get pod nginx-ingress-controller-8zxbf -n ingress-nginx -o yaml |grep configmap
    - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
    - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
    - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
```

```
[rancher@srv-rcnode01 ~]$ cat global-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  client-body-timeout: "360"
  client-header-timeout: "360"
  proxy-connect-timeout: "360"
  proxy-read-timeout: "360"
  proxy-send-timeout: "360"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
```

And apply:

```
kubectl apply -f global-configmap.yaml
```

Accessing the ingress pods and checking the nginx.conf, I see that annotations are created according to the parameters set inside the application block:

```
[rancher@srv-rcnode01 ~]$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx exec --stdin --tty nginx-ingress-controller-8zxbf -- /bin/bash
```

And view nginx.conf

```
keepalive_timeout 3600s;client_body_timeout 3600s;client_header_timeout 3600s;

# Custom headers to proxied server
            
            
            proxy_connect_timeout                   3600s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      3600s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      3600s;
```

What I noticed at the beginning of the nginx.conf file in the "server" configuration block is that it has default 60-second timeout values:

```
# Custom headers to proxied server
            
            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;
```

My question in this case is whether these values may be interfering with this problem, and how can I change these values in the k8s?

Has anyone gone through this situation or something and can give me a north?

Thanks!!

Comment: Its your local env or cloud? How did you deploy Ingress? Did you enforce ingress to use new configuration? Did you try to add specific path in your ingress `spec.rules.http.paths.path` according to minial requirements from [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource)

Comment: Hi. The environment is local. Yes, I applied the changes on the ingress, but no success.

Comment: This helped me for Rancher 2.4.4: select cluster -> System -> Resources -> Config -> Namespace: ingress-nginx -> nginx-configuration -> Edit -> Add Config Map Value -> Key -> proxy-read-timeout -> Value -> 360. Not sure if my cluster configuration is the same as yours.

Answer (score 13):

What you want to achieve was mentioned in `Nginx Documentation` in [Custom Configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/). It recommend to use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

```
$ cat configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-connect-timeout: "10"
  proxy-read-timeout: "120"
  proxy-send-timeout: "120"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/docs/examples/customization/custom-configuration/configmap.yaml \
    | kubectl apply -f -
```

> If the Configmap it is updated, NGINX will be reloaded with the new configuration.

After that, in `Ingress controller` pod, you should see entries like:

```
8 controller.go:137] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
8 controller.go:153] Backend successfully reloaded.
```

However, please keep in mind that higher timeout values are not recommended for `Nginx`. This information can be found in [Nginx Ingress - proxy-connect-timeout](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-connect-timeout):

> Sets the timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server. **It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.**

**Additional information:**

**1.** Sometimes, when `Nginx Ingress` cannot load new configuration, you can find log like below:

```
controller.go:149"] - Unexpected failure reloading the backend": Invalid PID number "" in "/tmp/nginx/pid"
```

To fix it, you just need to restart `Ingress pod`.

**2.** If you dont like default settings, you can create a [config template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/) in `Go language`.

Answer (score 2):

To update only the ingress, and not the entire controller, use the following.
Source: [Advanced Configuration with Annotations](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#summary-of-annotations)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-loteamento-spring-hml
  annotations:
    # for the NGINX's nginx-ingress 
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
    # for the default ingress-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
  labels:
    run: api-loteamento-spring-hml
spec:
  ingressClassName: yourIngressClass
  rules:
  - host: hml-api-loteamento-sp.gruposfa.bla.bla
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: api-loteamento-spring-hml
              port:
                number: 80
```

Comment: It don't work for me. I guess you use the nginx-ingress controller, but k8s default's ingress is  ingress-nginx, it is different.

Comment: @miemengniao correct, that is why I pointed to the documentation for NGINX ingress. You can still do the same thing with the default k8s ingress, you just have to find out what the [correct annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#custom-timeouts) are for theirs.

Comment: Useful thanks, also worth mentioning that if you are using the default k8s ingress, don't add the 's' to your seconds, it needs to just be the raw integer.  E.g. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: 10`

Comment: I added the example annotations if you are using the default k8s ingress

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same problem. proxy timeout values were not set as per defined values. So after changing metadata.annotations my issue resolved.

```
Previous Values -

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"

Working Values -

nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
```